# connect the google credits into google colab

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

It's the first time that I am trying to use google credits, so I apologize if it's a basic question. I am trying to see how to connect google credits into google colab by this site https://medium.com/@senthilnathangautham/colab-gcp-compute-how-to-link-them-together-98747e8d940e (you can open it by creating a new incognito window).

I am stucked in step 3 because I can't see any SSH in my google cloud. Also the numbers after the -L are fixed? If not, how can I found them?

```
gcloud compute ssh colab-backend --zone=europe-west4-a -L 8081:locahost:8081
```

**EDIT:** I am trying to run the above line of code in Google Cloud SDK Shell, but I have this error.

[image]

Also, I can't type in the terminal jupiter notebook. If I run the above code in the python 3 jupyter notebook I have this strange error.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, I had a very silly basic mistake. First of all your server should be linux and then write the following code in the windows command:

1. cloud compute ssh colab-backend --zone=europe-west4-a -L 8080:locahost:8081, change it into the zone of your project and port
2. type
   `jupyter notebook  --NotebookApp.allow_origin='https://colab.research.google.com'  --port=8888  --NotebookApp.port_retries=0 --no-browser`
3. copy past the link into 'local runtime' in your google colab.